# How to get IDA Pro to understand a virtual function table?

Tags: ida, c, hexrays, vtables, virtual-functions

I'm reversing an old DirectDraw game that uses DirectX 7.

I have a `LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7 g_lpDDSBack` and `g_lpDDSBack->BltFast` is being called but this is how it is decompiled in HexRays:

```
(*(int (__stdcall **)(struct IDirectDrawSurface7Vtbl *, int, int, LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7, RECT *, MACRO_DDBLTFAST))((int (__stdcall **)(_DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD))g_lpDDSBack->QueryInterface + 7))(
                                      g_lpDDSBack,
                                      x,
                                      y,
                                      pgf2->lpDDSrcSurface,
                                      &pgf2->rect,
                                      DDBLTFAST_SRCCOLORKEY);
```

For reference, here is the interface:

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE_( IDirectDrawSurface7, IUnknown )
{
    /*** IUnknown methods ***/
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface) (THIS_ REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR * ppvObj) PURE; // 0
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef) (THIS)  PURE; // 1
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release) (THIS) PURE; // 2
    /*** IDirectDrawSurface methods ***/
    STDMETHOD(AddAttachedSurface)(THIS_ LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7) PURE; // 3
    STDMETHOD(AddOverlayDirtyRect)(THIS_ LPRECT) PURE; // 4
    STDMETHOD(Blt)(THIS_ LPRECT,LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7, LPRECT,DWORD, LPDDBLTFX) PURE; // 5
    STDMETHOD(BltBatch)(THIS_ LPDDBLTBATCH, DWORD, DWORD ) PURE; // 6
    STDMETHOD(BltFast)(THIS_ DWORD,DWORD,LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7, LPRECT,DWORD) PURE; // 7
    // etc ...
```

So from the HexRays code `g_lpDDSBack->QueryInterface + 7`, we can see it's calling `g_lpDDSBack->BltFast`. But why doesn't HexRays directly call `BltFast`?

Answer (score 2):

HexRays doesn't call it because it doesn't know what is the value of `g_lpDDSBack->QueryInterface` in the common case.

Generally speaking you can define a structure as a `QueryInterface` type, where members of this structure are named according to the related function names and than you'll see the call as `g_lpDDSBack->QueryInterface->BltFast` .

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a bug in IDA pro. I can't seem to edit my original question so first, I want to point out an error I made in the original question.

---

When `g_lpDDSBack` is defined as `struct IDirectDrawSurface7Vtbl *g_lpDDSBack;`, then this was the output HexRays was showing:

```
(*(int (__stdcall **)(struct IDirectDrawSurface7Vtbl *, int, int, LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7, RECT *, MACRO_DDBLTFAST))((int (__stdcall **)(_DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD))g_lpDDSBack->QueryInterface + 7))(
                                      g_lpDDSBack,
                                      x,
                                      y,
                                      pgf2->lpDDSrcSurface,
                                      &pgf2->rect,
                                      DDBLTFAST_SRCCOLORKEY);
```

---

When `g_lpDDSBack` is defined as `LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7 g_lpDDSBack;`, then this was the output HexRays was showing:

```
(*((int (__stdcall **)(int, int, int, _DWORD, int, signed int))g_lpDDSBack->lpVtbl + 7))(
                       g_lpDDSBack,
                       x,
                       y,
                       pgf2->lpDDSrcSurface,
                       &pgf2->rect,
                       DDBLTFAST_SRCCOLORKEY);
```

Alright, now here are the instructions to fixing the bug (`g_lpDDSBack` is defined as `LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE7 g_lpDDSBack;`):

1. Select `lpVtbl` in `g_lpDDSBack->lpVtbl`, press y and then copy the contents of the textbox to a notepad. In this case, the contents were `struct IDirectDrawSurface7::IDirectDrawSurface7Vtbl *lpVtbl`.
2. Change the type to `int lpVtbl` and press OK
3. Press y again on `lpVtbl` and change the type back to its original type stored in notepad. In this case, it is `struct IDirectDrawSurface7::IDirectDrawSurface7Vtbl *lpVtbl`.

After doing this, this is how it looks like in HexRays (you might have to press F5 first):

```
g_lpDDSBack->lpVtbl->BltFast(g_lpDDSBack,
                                      x,
                                      y,
                                      pgf2->lpDDSrcSurface,
                                      &pgf2->rect,
                                      DDBLTFAST_SRCCOLORKEY);
```